# Is there any way to go back previous breakpoint during debugging in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there any way to go back to the previous breakpoint during debugging in WebStorm.

For example, I've set three breakpoints at the following line numbers 158, 159, 160. Currently, my program flow is at 159 number line through `Step Over`. Now I want to go back the 158 line

Is it possible in WebStorm?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature. Please vote for [WEB-38981](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38981) to be notified on any progress with it